# Консольный прогресс-бар для очистки папки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать прогресс бар для процесса очистки папки.
Папку очищаю вот такой командой

```
 shutil.rmtree('c:/temp', ignore_errors=True,)
```

Для этого существуют модули tqdm и progressbar, но как их приспособить для данной задачи?

Comment: На твоем месте я бы сначала отчищал все файлы в папке а потом и саму папку. А количество файлов в папке Это собственно и прогресс бар каждый удаленный файл -1 к прогресс бару.

Comment: можно попробовать `os.rmdir`, `os.unlink` подменить на свои версии, которые `progress_bar.update()` вызывают. Если изменения от запуска к запуску ожидаются относительно небольшие, то можно сохранять общее число папок, других записей, прошедшее время с предыдущего запуска, чтобы оценить сколько ещё записей предстоит удалить/сколько времени это потребует.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Оценить время выполнения программы и вывести в реальном времени процент исполнения программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700958/23044)

Comment: Функцию которая удаляет с начало  файлы, потом папки с помощью os.rmdir и os.remove я смог сделать а вот как двигать прогресс бар не понимаю

Comment: *"как двигать прогресс бар не понимаю"* -- это можно как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задать (чтобы большему кругу людей подошло) с простым примером: `for _ in range(100): if random.random() < 0.1: i+=1; t.update(i)`